# Issue with npm after reinstalling node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I recently reinstalled node.js (latest version, 9.8.0) on my computer (running windows 10) as it started to glitch out.

The problem is, now npm doesn't work. For example, upon entering `npm` in cmd, I get the error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:83:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:224:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:262:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:178:20)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:35:29
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:170:21)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at process.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:431:27)
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:83:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:224:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:262:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:178:20)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:234:20)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\set-user.js:23:20
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:35:29
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:170:21)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
    at process.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:431:27)
```

The node command works fine, though. Why would this happen?

Edit: I have tried reverting to the recommended Node.js version (8.10.0), but I am getting the same issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while ago. Try navigating to the file named `.npmrc`, in `C:\Users\%UserName%`, and deleting it.

Comment: That was it - Thanks!

Comment: in my case I actually had no .npmrc file, neither in my user directory and neither in app data's npm folder. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58479718/6181692) worked for me,

Answer (score 3):

To fix this in Windows, create a directory junction to your users folder that didn't have a space in it. You can run a command like this in an administrative powershell:

```
cmd /c mklink /J "C:\Users\myname" "C:\Users\My Name"
```

You can then use this junction as if it were your real user directory:

```
npm config set cache C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

npm config set prefix C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

(the above should update your user .npmrc file)

Comment: This is actually pretty smart, I didn't try this as I read this afterwards fixing my issue so for any future wanderers if above solution doesn't work for you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58479718/6181692) worked for me,

Answer (score 1):

This maybe related to the NPM cache that needs to be cleaned you can do it using:

```
    npm cache clean
```

Let me know if it helped....