# npm start command doesn't start development server

Tags: create-react-app

I was trying to build a basic React application using Create React App. After creating the React application using the command `npm install -g create-react-app` and then `create-react-app my-app`. (This was a workaround I had to use since I'm on Windows). According to Git Bash, it was able to successfully create a new React app. This is the specific message that was displayed:

```
Shreya Basu@SKINNYMAN MINGW64 ~/Workspace
$ create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Shreya Basu\Workspace\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\Shreya Basu\Workspace\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Shreya Basu\Workspace\my-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Shreya Basu\Workspace\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-scripts@3.4.3
+ react@16.13.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
added 1598 packages from 746 contributors and audited 1602 packages in 94.891s

70 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1
+ @testing-library/jest-dom@4.2.4
+ @testing-library/react@9.5.0
added 36 packages from 56 contributors and audited 1638 packages in 25.518s

70 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing template package using npm...

npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

removed 1 package and audited 1637 packages in 10.793s

70 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


Created git commit.

Success! Created my-app at C:\Users\Shreya Basu\Workspace\my-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd my-app
  npm start

Happy hacking!
```

However, when I try to use the command `npm start`, nothing happens, not even an error message. This is all that shows up:

```
$ npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Shreya Basu\Workspace\my-app
> react-scripts start
```

I checked to see if ignore-scripts was set to true but it was not. I also tried running these commands on CMD to see if that would make a difference by no luck. I'm not sure where I messed up? Any clue what I'm missing?

Additional Info:
package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running react-scripts start directly?

Comment: sorry i'm new to all of this. what command would i use to do that?

Comment: Just run `react-scripts start` in the root directory where the project is.

Comment: ```Shreya Basu@SKINNYMAN MINGW64 ~/Workspace/my-app (master)
$ react-scripts start
bash: react-scripts: command not found
``` 
I'm not sure if this what you meant but this is what I'm getting ^^

Comment: How about running npm start in the root directory

Comment: ```Shreya Basu@SKINNYMAN MINGW64 ~/Workspace/my-app/src (master)
$ npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Shreya Basu\Workspace\my-app
> react-scripts start
```
same message as the one in my original post

Comment: Have you looked at @teerapat 's answer?

Comment: yep, it doesn't really help resolve my issue though

Comment: Can you try reinstall the whole thing?

Comment: i've tried that too. it didn't help

Answer (score 2):

`create-react-app` does not work anymore. Based on [official docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started), you'll need command `npx create-react-app your-app`

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package
> using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses
> the latest version.

Comment: I tried using ```npx create-react-app your-app``` but my directory path has a space in it and I get  an error similar to the one mention in this post and I used the solution posted there:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62241269/14343685